# Scheduling job in Pentaho BI server

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-data-integration, pdi, spoon

I am using a pentaho community edition 7. I want to schedule a JOB with two sub transformations in it.

I want to schedule it to run on every monday. Can anyone please guide me in saving the files using the correct filepaths and schedule them from BI server.

Answer (score 0):

You can find a guidance for your question in an accepted answer here:
[How to deploy scheduled Kettle jobs on Pentaho BI server v6 CE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35705921/how-to-deploy-scheduled-kettle-jobs-on-pentaho-bi-server-v6-ce)

Basically:

- Add job file and xaction file (triggers job file) to Pentaho server
- Add transformation files to server's filesystem
- Schedule xaction file in Pentaho using "Schedule..." file action (Weekly, Monday, preferred time can be set up in pop-up dialog)